# How set a dynamically generated attribute name for a Blob?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an Expando model on App Engine. How do store images in Blob properties if the attribute name is a variable?

Let's say I post a bunch of images where I dont know the name beforehand. Is there any real, existing equivalent of my imagined `p.image[entry] = db.Blob(image)` code below?

```
images = self.request.arguments()
for entry in images:
    image = self.request.get(entry)
    ##some validation stuff
    p = Pictures()
    p.image[entry] = db.Blob(image)
    p.put()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you want `setattr`:

```
setattr(p.image, entry, db.Blob(image))
```